# How to populate dropdown in thymeleaf with hashmap set from controller

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, view, thymeleaf

I want the dropdown  in the view to be get filled with value set from the controller. In my controller using model attribute I have added the list limits

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/works", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String searchWorks(Model model){
     Map< Integer, String > limits = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        limits.put(20, "20件");
        limits.put(25, "25件");
        limits.put(30, "30件");
        limits.put(35, "35件");
        limits.put(40, "40件");
        limits.put(45, "45件");
        limits.put(50, "50件");
    model.addAttribute("limits",limits);
    model.addAttribute("limit",limit);
    return "workSituation";
  }
```

In view Page in order to populate the dropdown with the value set using model attribute I have used this code

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-control" name = "limit" id="limit" onchange="getList(this.value)">
                  <option selected>-- select number of items--</option>

                  <option data-th-each="limit : ${limits}"
                                      data-th-value="${limt.getKey()}" 
                                      data-th-text="${limt.getValue()}"  >

                   </select>
                  </div>
```

I am getting the error

```
caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "limt.getKey()"

caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "limt.getValue()"
```

What will be the cause for this. Actually dropdown is iterating 7 times(the number of records in the limits list) but the key and value is not able to fetch with code.What is the correct way to get the dropdown filled with

```
          <option value="20">20件</option>
          <option value="25">25件</option>
          <option value="30">30件</option>
          <option value="35">35件</option>
          <option value="40">40件</option>
          <option value="45">45件</option>
          <option value="50">50件</option>
```

Comment: it's `limit.getKey()` not `limt.getKey()`. same with .getValue(). i am not sure about the following but i think your want to use `th:text=""` instead of data-th-text and `th:value=""` instead of data-th-value. Not exactly sure if data-th-* does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks It working fine. Actually data-th-* does the same thing as th. I am getting the list not as in the order I am inserted what will be the reason

Comment: a hashmap does not maintain the order of the elements. try to use a linkedhashmap for that. Good to know the data-th-* thing

Answer (score 0):

For thymeleaf try the following

```
<option th:each="limit : ${limits.entrySet()}" th:value="${limit.key}" th:text="${limit.value}"></option>
```